# ogr2ogr download GeoJSON from URL with parameters

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr

I have this working URL query for this
[dataset](https://data.ny.gov/Economic-Development/Retail-Food-Stores/9a8c-vfzj)

```
https://data.ny.gov/resource/9a8c-vfzj.geojson?$limit=100000&$$app_token=mytoken&$where=county in('Kings','Queens','Bronx','Richmond','New York')
```

Now I want to pull it and save it to a GeoJSON with ogr2ogr

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" /home/thefile.geojson "https://data.ny.gov/resource/9a8c-vfzj.geojson?$limit=100000&$$app_token=mytoken&$where=county in('Kings','Queens','Bronx','Richmond','New York')" OGRGeoJSON -s_srs EPSG:4326 -progress

ERROR 1: HTTP error code : 400
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `https://data.ny.gov/resource/9a8c-vfzj.geojson?=100000&39457app_token=mytoken&=county in('Kings','Queens','Bronx','Richmond','New York')' with the following drivers.
```

the URL query works when I put it in the browser so I am wondering what the problem could be. I took out New York too see if it was the spaces in the URL being executed from the CMD but still no luck.

Comment: It seems like $ signs are interpreted to have some special meaning. Try to escape them as `\$`.  For more detailed messages add `--debug on  --config CPL_DEBUG on` to your command.

Comment: If the url is already giving you geojson, why do you need ogr2ogr?

Comment: @jbalk was going to pipe it into postgres

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find a working sample code below to directly get the data from the URL and push it to a PostGIS table (I've considered you already have an existing database and ran `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

```bsh
ogr2ogr \
        -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost dbname=yourdbname user=yourusername password=yourpassword" \
        -lco OVERWRITE=yes \
        -lco SCHEMA=public \
        -gt 65536 \
        --config PG_USE_COPY YES \
        -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom \
        -nln your_wanted_table_name_in_postgis \
        'https://data.ny.gov/resource/9a8c-vfzj.geojson?$limit=100000&$where=county%20in(%27Kings%27,%27Queens%27,%27Bronx%27,%27Richmond%27,%27New%20York%27)'
```

PS: Tested on Linux, with Bash. Single quotes around remote url are important to avoid escaping `$` character with `\$`.

Comment: thanks this worked well

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I tried to use -s_srs without also using -t_srs:

`ERROR 5: if -s_srs is specified, -t_srs and/or -spat_srs must also be specified.`

I was able to save a geojson file by using this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" test.geojson "https://data.ny.gov/resource/9a8c-vfzj.geojson?$limit=100000&$where=county%20in(%27Kings%27,%27Queens%27,%27Bronx%27,%27Richmond%27,%27New%20York%27)" OGRGeoJSON -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -progress
```

Please note that I removed the apptoken from the url because I don't have one.

Comment: It could be a bit more effective to use `/vsicurl/"https://data..."`  https://erouault.blogspot.com/2012/05/new-gdal-virtual-file-system-to-read.html.

Comment: No need for `-s_srs EPSG:4326` or `-t_srs EPSG:4326`: your data is already `EPSG:4326`

Comment: i got a similar error to mine with your code...but noted with the escape characters